# Shared ZMQ Socket PHP

Tags: php, zeromq

How to create a shared ZMQ socket using PHP? The scenario is

1. User1 logs in to the system - A ZMQ bind happens and the user stays in the system
2. User2 logs in to the system - Bind exception arises because of socket address already in use

How should we handle this issue using ZMQ?

Comment: You really should add the programming language as a tag to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question is this post in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952209/zmq-getsocket-method)

Method: `ZMQContext::getSocket ( integer $type [, string $persistent_id = null [, callback $on_new_socket = null ]] )`

> Shortcut for creating new sockets from the context. If the context is
>   not persistent the persistent_id parameter is ignored and the socket
>   falls back to being non-persistent. The on_new_socket is called only
>   when a new underlying socket structure is created

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use bind() for one process, and connect() for the other.

From the ZMQ Guide http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all:

To create a connection between two nodes you use zmq_bind(3) in one node, and zmq_connect(3) in the other. As a general rule of thumb, the node which does zmq_bind(3) is a "server", sitting on a well-known network address, and the node which does zmq_connect(3) is a "client", with unknown or arbitrary network addresses. Thus we say that we "bind a socket to an endpoint" and "connect a socket to an endpoint", the endpoint being that well-known network address.