# ZMQ getsocket method

Tags: php, zeromq

What is the purpose of getSocket(type,persistence_id,callback) in zeromq?

Will it create a new socket if one doesn't exist with the same persistence_id in the context?

This is my client

```php
function newSocket(ZMQSocket $soc, $pid)    {
    echo $pid;
}

$context = new ZMQContext();

$socket = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH, 'mysocket', 'newSocket');

$socket->setSockOpt(ZMQ::SOCKOPT_HWM,5);

$socket->connect("tcp://172.16.136.59:5555");
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
{
    var_dump($socket->send("hai",ZMQ::MODE_NOBLOCK));
    sleep(2);
}
```

How many ever times I run this client simultaneously[nth client after n-1th client started], the callback is getting executed.
Is this the desired behavior?
What are all the situations, where the socket structure will be reused?

Comment: Did you take a look at the documentation? If this is php, take a look at http://php.zero.mq/zmqcontext.getsocket.html

Comment: Thanks for ur response ZeissS. And btw I did referred that documentation from where I found this method. But the issue is I'm not clear abt "this Callback function, which is executed when a new socket structure is created. This function does not get invoked if the underlying persistent connection is re-used". What do they mean by "underlying persistent connection"?

Comment: ZMQ reuses sockets when connecting to another server. You may want to take a look at the ZMQ Documentation itself to understand some concepts there. I dont know enough about zmq to help you here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What persistance does is signal the memory allocator to use the persistent memory allocation functions, which will alloc the context (and if you ask, any sockets) in a way that wont go away at the end of the request, but will last the lifetime of a PHP process. It sort of works the same way as some of the connection pooling libs, if that makes sense. The callback will be used on the first time the socket is created. Persistance needs to be set in the context, for example:

```
<?php

function newSocket(ZMQSocket $soc, $pid)    {
    echo "Creating New Socket \n", $pid, "\n";
}

echo "=========Creating without persistence ==========\n";

$context = new ZMQContext(1, false);

$socket = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH, 'mysocket', 'newSocket');

$socket = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH, 'mysocket', 'newSocket');

echo "========Creating with persistence ==========\n";

$context = new ZMQContext(1, true);

$socket = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH, 'mysocket', 'newSocket');

$socket = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH, 'mysocket', 'newSocket');
```

Will give you

```
# php -dextension=zmq.so test.php 
=========Creating without persistence ==========
Creating New Socket 
mysocket
Creating New Socket 
mysocket
========Creating with persistence ==========
Creating New Socket 
mysocket
```

In the first instance, with false to persistance, the socket is recreated each time, and the callback fired. In the second, with persistance on, the socket is just returned, and the callback not triggered.

Comment: That was awesome :) I use push pull socket. Push side does a bind and uses persistent context. I do `ab -n 10000 -c 300 http://workspace/zmq/zmqPTS.php` and I find that we loose around 100 to 200 msgs. Can you guess why would it happen? Is that because of "slow joiner" symptom?? How can I overcome this issue?